# How to check username/password without signing in the user

Tags: plugin-development, users, authentication

I'm writing a plugin that creates an API endpoint that validates username/password pairs.

I'm currently using [`wp_signon()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) to check whether the username/password combo works. This works fine when the credentials fail because it returns an error object. But when the credentials are good, it automatcially signs in that user, so my endpoint returns a whole page.

[The codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) currently doesn't even mention the fact that it automatically logs in the user. It also doesn't appear to accept a parameter to suppress that functionality. For my purposes I simple boolean would be fine.

**UPDATE:**
I had to choose one single answer, but there was a lot of useful info several of the other answers which I'll try to summarize briefly here...

1. There IS a function that does exactly what I was trying to do: `wp_authenticate($username, $password)` HOWEVER, it comes with one drawback. It will automatically set the login cookies which can create problems in a situation like mine. So be careful. This function is not currently in the codex.
2. The best choice for what I'm doing is `wp_authenticate_username_password($user, $username, $password)` because it DOESN'T set the login cookies. This function is more documented, but the REALLY important detail that wasn't in the codex is that you can pass `NULL` as the first parameter. This means you can effectively use it to do exactly like `wp_authenticate()` without worrying about the cookies getting screwed up. Read the documentation so you don't get confused by the response. It returns a either a WP_User object or a WP_Error (not a boolean!).

Comment: The Codex is user driven. Just log in and change/edit/add what you think is missing. (Look at it, like you look at Wikipedia).

Comment: Note: wp_authenticate doesn't actually set the login cookies, that happens in wp_signon. However, wp_authenticate will apply all hooked authentication methods, so if a valid auth-cookie is sent along with the request, then it can validate the user regardless of the username/password. If you just want to check the username password, wp_authenticate_username_password is indeed correct.

Comment: did you ever release this plugin/endpoint?

Comment: @d3vid This was for a private project from years ago, so the code would need to be updated to be compatible with current WP. But if this is something you're interested in email me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a function in the [`user.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/user.php#L71) of the core files called [`wp_authenticate_username_password`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_authenticate_username_password/) that seems like what you're looking for.

If you want to avoid throwing in the `$user` object (you probably only have the username + password), then just throw `null` as 1st function argument in:

```
$check = wp_authenticate_username_password( NULL, 'some_username', '#thepassw0rd' );
```

You can then simply check the result with `is_wp_error( $check )`.

Comment: This doesn't do what it sounds like. It's a common mistake (which I've made). However, I just discovered a function which actually does what we want! See me answer...

Comment: +1 seems to be the perfect way. I hope you don't mind the edit.

Comment: @kaiser "Huh". I never realized you could pass NULL as the first parameter. That's good to know. Also check out `wp_authenticate()` (see my answer). I just found it after weeks of searches.

Comment: Definitely most efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

Use,

- [`get_user_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by)

and

- [`get_userdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)

### Explanation

```
// get user by login via the supplied username (form input)
$user = get_user_by('login', $username);

//assign user ID based on user login name
$user_id = $user->ID;

// get user data by passing the assigned $user_id variable to get_userdata
// which returns the user object and a host of user related info to access
$user_data = get_userdata($user_id);


// assign the username and password to variables
$user_login = $user_data->user_login;
$user_pass = $user_data->user_pass;

// check the username/password against the submitted input values
if ($user_login = $username && $user_pass = $password) {

// do something...
```

---

### Notes

- `$username` should validate true by default otherwise a user object would not have been returned if the `$username` supplied did not match one already existing in the database. Therefore the validation then hinges on the `$password` variable which stores the form input supplied by the user.
- There might be a more efficient way for you to achieve this, either by shortening the existing code or by using other API functions.

## UPDATE

Based upon the suggestion by  **fdsa** you could in turn use `wp_authenticate_username_password` in this fashion,

```
$auth = wp_authenticate_username_password($user, $username, $password);

if (!$auth->user_login = $username && !$auth->user_pass = $password) {

echo 'not authenticated';

} else {

echo 'authenticated';

}
```

But even better than that,

```
$auth = wp_authenticate_username_password($user, $username, $password);

if (is_wp_error($auth)) {

echo 'not authenticated';

} else {

echo 'authenticated';

}
```

Really the credit/marked answer ought to be given to **fdsa** for the most efficient method by way of (sadly) undocumented WP core function.

http://wpseek.com/wp_authenticate_username_password/

Comment: This is great. But `get_userdata` will return the hashed password (not the plaintext). Any advice how to sidestep this?

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: This answer should just show what's going on behind the scenes and is not meant to be a real life example on how to do things.*

---

### Backtrace

[`wp_signon()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/user.php#L72) calls [`wp_set_auth_cookie()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L652), which then calls [`wp_generate_auth_cookie()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_generate_auth_cookie/). The result will be used inside `setcookie()` as 2<sup>nd</sup> argument.

### (Non-performant) fun with filters

<sup>a.k.a. tricking WordPress the wrong way.</sup>

You could then just jump into the `'auth_cookie'`-filter inside `wp_generate_auth_cookie()` and simply set it to null or something else than the `SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE` or `AUTH_COOKIE` value. This will then leave you with a senseless cookie, that can't log in.

Answer (score 0):

"Ta-da": `wp_authenticate($username, $password)`

[It's not in the codex at all, but you can look it up on wpseek](http://wpseek.com/wp_authenticate/).

It does exactly what it sounds like. Takes a username and plain text password and returns either a `WP_User` object or a `WP_Error`... and it DOESN'T log anyone in.

One note of caution! The following will ALWAYS return true (because the function returns an object either way):

```
$auth = ( wp_authenticate($username, $password) ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

You'll probably want to do something like this:

```
$test_creds = wp_authenticate($username, $pass) ;
$class = get_class($test_creds);
$auth = ( $class == 'WP_User' ) ? TRUE : FALSE ;
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: You can use `instanceof` or `is_a()` to check for `WP_User`. You could also simply use one of the above functions and remove the filter on `authenticate`...

Comment: Recommend using `is_wp_error($auth)` which will return `TRUE` if fails authentication and `FALSE` if passes authentication.

Comment: One more note: This will not log you in, but it will still leave you with the cookie set, as [the function](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/user.php#L120) calls the `'authenticate  filter. If you go with that solution, you should make **sure**, that all filter callbacks are removed. Else the sky could fall on your head :)

Comment: That's good to know about. Does `wp_authenticate_username_password( NULL, 'some_username', '#thepassw0rd' );` have the same problem? Can you elaborate slightly on the sky falling? What will go wrong?

Comment: Note: Instead of using `wp_authenticate` you want to actually use `user_pass_ok($user_login, $user_pass)` which in turn uses `wp_authenticate` as its the proper wrapper function which returns `true/false`. However as @kaiser said, cookie is set via `authenticate` filter. The latter `wp_authenticate_username_password` does not appear to set cookie.

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_authenticate) `wp_authenticate()` DOES log the user in if the login credentials are correct. Strangely it doesn't do that for me.